# Unbalanced quotes with csquotes (by design, not by mistake)

Tags: csquotes

I'm trying to get the hang of `csquotes` and found a situation that I'm not being able to work around.

Suppose the following scenario. In citing an author in a long `blockquote` this author, in turn, cites another passage, thus deserving quotes. However, this passage, spans more than one paragraph. It is customary (correct me if I'm wrong) at the beginning of the new paragraph to open quotes again, without having being closed. (As a reminder, "this is still a quote"). And only close it when the cited passage finally ends.

I can fake the effect by adding the quote marks manually (this is what is done in the MWE below). But, is there a way to do the same thing within `csquotes` logic?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}

\begin{document}

\blockquote[Citation]{The wise man used to say:
“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, 
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem.

``Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

``Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.”

As you all see, he was a wise man indeed.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is not too much to add a second (minor) point on top of the question. (If it is, leave it be. The main issue is the above.) Do you think it is a good idea to use the unicode English quotes as active characters to supply to `csquotes` as I do here? Do you expect any trouble with this setting? Is there something which is typically better/more practical than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is usual in english. But you can define a quotestyle which adds such middle marks (see also in csquotes.def the french `guillemets*` style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{englishmiddle}% 
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [\textquotedblleft]
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}
\setquotestyle {englishmiddle} 
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}

\begin{document}

\blockquote[Citation]{The wise man used to say:
“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem.

Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.”

As you all see, he was a wise man indeed.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike, thank you! This is certainly the proper way to do this. And, yes, I'm not writing in English, but (Brazilian) Portuguese. I might be wrong that this is the proper way to typeset the quotes in Portuguese, but somehow I'm "used to it" and they "feel correct" this way. It might be the all pervasive French influence around here (up to one or two generations ago).

Comment: This style is not at all uncommon in English: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96608. Example: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2017/dec/22/frantic-friday-sees-millions-hit-uk-roads-at-height-of-christmas-getaway